# Node depth rpart

Tags: r, tree, nodes, depth, rpart

I am growing a classification tree using rpart. I need the depth of each node in order to identify the nodes that are more isolated (more distant from the parent node) and the nodes that are closer to the parent node. Does anybody know how can I get this information? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the depth you want is the number of parents or the number of children. It might help to use the `depth()` method from the `partykit` package which computes the number of levels of children. You can use this when coercing from `rpart` to `party` and then using `nodeapply()`:

```
## packages
library("rpart")
library("partykit")
## rpart tree
rp <- rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris)
## coercion to party
pr <- as.party(rp)
plot(pr)
## query depth of each node
nodeapply(pr, ids = nodeids(pr), depth)
## $`1`
## [1] 2
## 
## $`2`
## [1] 0
## 
## $`3`
## [1] 1
## 
## $`4`
## [1] 0
## 
## $`5`
## [1] 0
```

You can look at the source code of `depth.party()` to see how this cycles recursively through the tree. A similar code could be used to find the number of layers of parents.